# send full address to php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have this line of code

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>Address (New Format):</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <?php 
        $address =$this->commonModel->getById('locations','id',$task->address); 
    ?>
  <p>
      <a href="javascript:;" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="" data-original-title="Select Address" 
          class="editable editable-click contactaddress" style="color: gray;">
          <?php echo $address->name.' - '.$address->address; ?>&nbsp;
      </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The table fields are |address|city|state|PostalCode|

How can I have the $address variable receive all 4 fields, not just the first?

I have tried

$task->address, city, state

and

$task->address, $task->city, etc

the common model code is

```
public function getById($table,$id,$value){
        $qry =$this->db->query('select * from '.$table.' where '.$id.'="'.$value.'" order by '.$id.' desc');
        return $qry->row();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At database level you can concatenate all values in address

```
select CONCAT(address,city,state,PostalCode) address from '.$table.' where '.$id.'="'.$value.'" order by '.$id.' desc
```

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure why I didn't think of ConCat

Comment: Please invite so that it can help others.